# Calculate area percentage of a polygon layer inside a polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-pro, intersection

There are two polygon layers,

1. State boundaries of a country
2. Soil class of the country with three classes

The soil class containing only 2 major classes and the 3rd soil class is unimportant(very small area).

How it is possible to calculate the area percentage of the 2 major soil class alone based on the state boundary ?

For example:

| State | soil class1 | soil class 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| State 1 | 53% | 47% |
| State 2 | 55% | 45% |

After intersecting the two polygons how can I calculate only the area percentage of only two soil classes to 100% by excluding the 3rd soil class ?

Comment: And that's why you need to add correct tags right from the start.